# ProgressBar giving me NullPointerException on AnimationListener

Tags: java, android, animation, nullpointerexception, progress-bar

I'm working on a project and I added a `ProgressBar` to my Intent. The `ProgressBar` sits on top of an Image.

Whenever I add the following code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_greet);


        pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);


        pb.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

        Intent intent = new Intent(Greet.this, SearchField.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

I get a `nullPointerException`

when I remove the

```
pb.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
```

the error is gone.

I can't figure out why I'm getting the NullPointerException, looking over the code, everything seems how it should be.

I feel like I'm about to learn something new here because I cleaned the project, tried it out and error keeps occurring regardless.. so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

EDIT:

ActivityGreet in XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".Greet" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fitnessPic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
        android:src="@drawable/appleorange"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Are there known issues with placing a ProgressBar on an Image?

Comment: None of the suggestions at the bottom worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure a `ProgressBar` with id `progressBar1` exists in your activity_greet layout.
2. Make sure you're importing your project's `R` class, and not `android.R`, since there might be a chance that `android.R` also contains an `R.id.progressBar1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think You haven't defined animation in */res/anim* folder. Change your code like this:

```
ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar1);
Animation progressAnimation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.progressAnim);
pb.startAnimation(progressAnimation);
```

And separately implement your animation listener instead of making it anonymous.

See [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) for more detail.